# When I manually start my own service it runs in the foreground, is this correct?

Tags: 12.04, bash, services

I have created my own service by:

1. copying my binary to `/usr/bin/mcp`
2. Create a daemon copying the skeleton: `/etc/init.d/skeleton`
3. Modify the skeleton bash script top:

   ```
   PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
   DESC="Runs my Service"
   NAME=mcp
   DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME
   DAEMON_ARGS="-d f -c /etc/mcp"
   PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
   SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
   ```

   Other than this the skeleton is exactly the same.
4. Then I create the daemon:

   ```
   sudo update-rc.d -f mcp remove
   sudo update-rc.d mcp defaults 97 03
   ```

When I run the program manually: `mcp -d f -c /etc/mcp`, it works, but it never returns since its a service that is meant to always run. This is normal.

But now when I start it as a service: `sudo service mcp start`, I see the same behavior. I.e. as soon as I enter the start service command, the program runs, but now my terminal is stuck waiting for the program.

I thought if you run something as a service then it should be running in the background?

Also I can't stop this service unless I open a second terminal. I kind of want it so that when I start the service it starts somewhere in the background and then you return to the command line. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Don't use an init.d service. Write an Upstart job instead. Here's an example: http://askubuntu.com/a/581869/158442. Upstart will take care of keeping the program in the background, logging, etc.

Comment: @muru Thanks - this looks far more simple. How do I stop / re-start the service (lets say it hangs/crashes)?

Comment: `service mcp restart`, or `restart mcp`, if your Upstart configuration is in `/etc/init/mcp.conf`

Comment: @muru I basically copied your code example (with my executable path) - do I need to add some "upstart" line in there too?

Comment: @muru: I think that qualifies as an answer...  Do you want to do the honours or should I create a community answer?

Comment: @code_fodder Depends. Where did you copy it to? `/etc/init/mcp.conf`? Or some file in `/etc/init.d`?

Comment: @Fabby go ahead. Don't make it a wiki.

Comment: @muru I really copied exactly what you wrote in your link, so I made my file: /etc/init/mcp.conf. All it contains is the description, the start/stop line and the exec line...

Comment: @code_fodder that should be enough. You might want to remove or rename the file you created in `init.d`.

Comment: @muru So, I restarted my PC after removing my old init.d attempt. I saw that my binary was running : )  ... but when I type `service mcp stop` it says `unknown job: mcp`.   Also nothing in service --status-all list that I reconise

Comment: @code_fodder forgot `sudo`?

Comment: @muru ahh....yes that did it :o ... thanks very much for all your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an `init.d` service. Write an Upstart job instead. [Here's an example](https://askubuntu.com/a/581869/158442). Upstart will take care of keeping the program in the background, logging, etc.

Your service would be in `/etc/init/mcp.conf`, containing, for example:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop  on runlevel [016]

exec /usr/bin/mcp -d f -c /etc/mcp
```

Then you can do:

```
sudo service mcp start
sudo service mcp stop
```

And so on.

Comment: lol, thanks very much - that must be a very delayed reaction from nearly a year ago! ... I would also up-vote you, but I spent my points on a bounty so I can upvote : (

Comment: Eh, that's alright. I just answered it now to remove it from the unanswered list. :D

Comment: Got my points now, so +1 : p